# How to show Location Services settings over (under) my app settings

Tags: ios, swift, settings, preferences

I customized my app settings (in iPhone settings page) by using root.plist.
Now how can I add location services and notifications to my settings so user can see all my app preferences in single place?

I need something like this, so I can both see Location permission and my custom settings in same place :

[image]

Comment: I think these options show up automatically as soon as you start using notifications, location service etc...

Comment: in your app you can 't manipulate system settings, `settings` app is used for same, but settings like remote notifiactions you can handle using servers

Answer (score 3):

So, Location Settings will show up automatically in the Settings, when you list Location as a capability in your app. If you want more of your custom settings to show up inside Settings, and not inside your app, you can add keys in plist files for the Settings Bundle.

Refer: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Answer (score -1):

You can get current status of location configuration using [authorizationStatus()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423523-authorizationstatus) and [locationServicesEnabled()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423648-locationservicesenabled) and according to status, you can display in your settings.

But there is NO way to modify Location configuration form your custom setting.